# On X86-64 Ubuntu 20.04, how come my 32-bit executable isn't?

Tags: 20.04, 64-bit, 32-bit, g++

I am trying to build a 32-bit executable (to see if it runs faster) on x86_64 Ubuntu 20.04 running on WSL on Windows 10. If I build the same code without the -m32 option in g++, the result runs. If I build it with -m32, it doesn't.  Here is the complete sequence:

```
jon@2014Laptop:~/projects/KSolve$ uname --m
x86_64
jon@2014Laptop:~/projects/KSolve$ g++ -m32 -g speeder.cpp Game.cpp KSolve.cpp -I. -o speeder
jon@2014Laptop:~/projects/KSolve$ file speeder
speeder: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV),
 dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, 
 BuildID[sha1]=3212c37b68b4eb6aec34e957739275dc272ecb86, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0,
 with debug_info, not stripped
jon@2014Laptop:~/projects/KSolve$ ./speeder
-bash: ./speeder: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

jon@2014Laptop:~/projects/KSolve$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Similar question was asked in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36896713/1525392), the accepted answer stated that WSL does not support 32 bit binaries. But Froosh later said that it is possible using [qemu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49405982/1525392).

Comment: Thank you.  I switched to running Linux on a virtual machine and found that the 32-bit version ran a little slower than the 64-bit version.